# PHP Email Form More Fields

Tags: php, html, email, post

So I have an email form using PHP:

```
<form method="post" action="contactus.php" autocomplete="off">
            <label for="Name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" maxlength="60" required/>

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" maxlength="120" required/>

            <label for="message">Message:</label><br />
            <textarea name="message" rows="20" cols="20" id="message" required></textarea>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
        </form>
```

And the PHP to send to my email:

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {

// The message
$message=$_POST["message"];

$email=$_POST["email"];

// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

// Send
mail('myemail.com', 'Quick Pass', $message, $email);
}
?>
```

But the problem is only 'myemail.com' (which is my email address), 'Quick Pass' (the email subject) and $message (the email message). $email isn't being sent.

I have tried:

```
<?php
$to = "myemail.com";
$subject = "Quick Pass";
$message=$_POST["message"];
$email=$_POST["email"];

mail($to,$subject,$message,$email);
?>
```

With this I am receiving four emails (two with $message and two with $email).

The problem is I need all of this in one email. So the $message is sent along with $email somewhere in the email.

Any ideas? (hopefully using my form)

Comment: The fourth parameter of the mail function is for headers, not some random email addresses. Please also have a look at [http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: So any help of how to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example, direct from the php manual, which looks as follows:-

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The fourth parameter is NOT simply an email address - it is a header:value type arrangement with multiple headers separated using \r\n

In your code perhaps you could try:-

```
if($_POST["submit"]) {

    // The message
    $message=$_POST["message"];

    $email=$_POST["email"];

    $headers='From: '.$email."\r\n".
        'Reply-To: '.$email;

    // In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
    $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

    // Send
    mail('myemail@example.com', 'Quick Pass', $message, $headers );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried that but it didn't work, again just sending the message content. Where is the $mail coming from?

Comment: I have just noticed(!) the email address in your $to variable - its missing the @

Comment: No that was just an example, my email is different and does have a @. Where is the $mail coming from in your example?

Comment: That was initially a typo - it should have been $email in accordance with the posted variable - corrected that as soon as i saw my mistook.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you getting your form input correctly. then try this.

```
// recipients
$to = 'to@example.com'; //your email address
$user_email = $_POST["email"]; //input from form
// subject
$subject = 'Subject';
// message
$message = $_POST["message"];
// set conent type
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: User Email <'.$user_email.'>' . "\r\n";
// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Thank you. But this is for a form, so the user types in their email address. So I won't know who the From: Your Name <from@example.com>' would be

Comment: if you don't need it just don't add as I have update the code for you. and make you put your correct email address .. please ... it should work.

Comment: But your example doesn't show the users email address, which is what I need

Comment: I have updated the code again for you. try now and let me know please

Comment: I thought that would work, but the email won't send at all now (I haven't received any email)

Comment: is your script live? it would not go if its not live. its working for me !

Comment: Yeah its live. The examples I have in my question successfully get sent to my email, I copied and paste your code (changed the email to@example.com to my email obviously) but won't receive an email, not sure why. I was just wondering is it possible to receive multiple inputs from the same form, for example: $message=$_POST["message, email"];

Answer (score 0):

As previous posters have said, the fourth parameter id for for headers so it should be "From: {$email}" or similar.

However, mail servers are sometimes configured to ignore From headers and set a default value. Also you could find that the message is being ignored somewhere along the email route (by your host's own relay server or by your email provider's incoming mail server) if the sending address doesn't match any DNS MX records for the domain in question. You will need to talk to your hosting provider(s) to investigate this.